# How do I learn the basic of android UI creation?

Tags: android

I am new to Android. Is there any way we can design our layout with out any controls. I am using Relative layout but if I change one button, entire layout is disturbed. It is becoming very difficult to align buttons in custom way. Do we have any other layout which allow user to keep views in his desired position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you are using a `RelativeLayout`, and that is the base cause for your troubles right now.

In a `RelativeLayout`, all elements define their positions relative to either the parent, or other elements in the layout. So if you have 10 elements, which depend on each other in the order `1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 4 <- 5 <- 6 <- 7 <- 8 <- 9 <- 10`, and you change the position of element 5. This will directly affect the position of element 6, and cause a domino effect right upto 10, effectively messing up your layout.

However, `RelativeLayouts` are very flexible and useful layouts, once you get the hang of using them. On the other hand, if you're simply stacking Views one on top of the other, consider using a `LinearLayout`.

The documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) can be particularly helpful when selecting a layout.

Comment: now i understand it clearly. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can always edit the xml manually instead of using the wysiwyg ui editor. That way you understand layouts and widgets better.

Comment: yeah, I have started editing xml. thank you.

Comment: @samuelebe If my answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking on he tick icon. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please read this document http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html. There is all you can need for a beginner in android. It's may be a bit boring, but really usefull.

Answer (score 1):

developing environment in android, programmers prefer 
Relative Layout to make GUI/Screens as they are very flexible and device independent, but in your case you make a layout and change a button this will surely cause problem. In Relative layout everything is dependent on some other widgets so from top to bottom and left to right make your hierarchy. Start from top-left and go to right-bottom.

Basics in relative layout 
use toLeftOf, toRightOf, alignParentRight, centerInParent, centerHorizontal, centerVertical.

Other than that use width and height of widget as wrap-content if you are using custom graphics, otherwise use width/height of widgets in dp, font in sp.

Best of luck.

Comment: thanks for clarification. Will follow that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many layouts available. RelativeLayout is the one in which everything is positioned relative to each other. This obviously means that changes to one element tend to effect on others. If you want more robust layouts you can use any combinations of LineraLayout, FrameLayout, TableLayout, GridLayout and RelativeLayout. You can construct anything without using RelativeLayouts at all, but then again it might mean your layout XML will become very bloated (and possibly slow to render). Remember that you can mix and match. So if you want to position a list of things at certain point on the screen you could use a top level RelativeLayout to position a nested LinearLayout (vertical). In this way changing the order and/or adding/removing stuff from the list is not so tedious.